# Probability in a multiple choice test

Tags: probability

Let's say a multiple choice test has 12 questions which can be answered with "yes" or "no".
The correct answer to six of them is "yes".

What is the probability to answer at least 8 questions correct if you randomly answer 6 questions with "yes" and the other six with "no"?

Comment: Well I think answering a question right is still a 50:50 thing so the probability of passing the test with at least 8 correct answers would be

the sum from 8 to 12 of 12ck * (1/2)^12

Answer (score 1):

Let Y be the number of correct answers for the 6 questions that were answered 'yes'.
Let X be the number of correct answers for the 6 questions that were answered 'no'.
Now, note that if Y = 1, it means you have answered 'yes' to 5 of the questions whose correct answer is 'no'.
That means you have answered 5 of the questions whose answer is 'no' incorrectly.
That means we must have X = 1.
By a similar argument, the result will be true for Y = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.
So, the set of possible outcomes $(Y, X)$ = {(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6)}.

We want $P(Y+X \ge 8)$.

Equivalently, we want $P(Y \ge 4)$ where Y is $Binomial(12, \frac{6}{12})$

and you should be able to work out the rest of the details.